# Should we still create instances if we want to take advantage of dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, instantiation, constructor-injection

I am getting deeper into the Dependency Injection concept and more I read, more I like the idea behind it. I have been using it for some time already, but still many things confuse me every now and then, and I feel that I am not using its full potential.

Imagine the code below. In this class, (probably a few things can be improved but..) we have one method that returns a string value. There is no need for constructor injection (or at least that's what I think, correct me if I am wrong), but then at the last line in the **try** block, we create new instance of the StreamReader class to be able to pass the response stream to it and to get the result using the **ReadToEnd** method.

The idea behind Dependency Injection is to avoid creating instances inside a class, but how to deal with this scenario?

```
public class WebClientService : IWebClientService
{    
        public async Task<String> GetApiResponseAsync(string Url)
        {
            String responseText = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    return new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogMessageDispatcher.Instance.Log(e);
                }
                return null;
            });

            return responseText;
        }
}
```

I am going over 'Mark Seemann's book - Dependency Injection', but I still have a lot to cover.

Comment: @mark-seemenn: I would highly appreciate it if I can get your opinion on this. 


-There are probably other similar scenarios that bother me, so anyone trying to answer, please don't give me other approaches or advise me to use different libraries to make the Http request. 


-Instead, offer me a solution that will keep the same approach - using the HttpWebRequest... It will help me understand the DI relation of my problem and the solution.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea behind Dependency Injection is to avoid creating instances inside a class, but how to deal with this scenario?

That's not at all the point. One of the central points of DI is to enable *loose coupling* to **Volatile Dependencies**. Not all types a class depends on are *volatile*. Some are *stable* and there is no need to prevent creating stable dependencies from within a class. Chapter one of both [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://manning.com/seemann) (by Mark Seemann) and its successor [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (by Mark and I) have a detailed description of what [Volatile Dependencies](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/section-1-3-2) and [Stable Dependencies](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/section-1-3-1) are and how they differ.

The main question you should ask is whether any of the types that `WebClientService` depend on are Volatile Dependencies or not. The answer depends on your particular context, and you should be able to figure this out after (re)reading chapter 1. This chapter can be read online freely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got two other pretty descriptive answers, as well. 

I have read somewhere something along the lines of 'When one tries to apply particular solution perfectly (of some newly learned pattern or principle), usually, in the beginning, he will make the things about 30-35% worse then what they would be without the pattern.' :)

Anyways, I get your point and indeed I am going over chapter 1 again.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very trivial example and relatively easy to define as your coupling is a basic Class without any service related functionality. Let's start from the definition of DI in wikipedia:

> In software engineering, dependency injection is a technique whereby one object supplies the dependencies of another object. A "dependency" is an object that can be used, for example as a service. Instead of a client specifying which service it will use, something tells the client what service to use. The "injection" refers to the passing of a dependency (a service) into the object (a client) that would use it. The service is made part of the client's state.[1] Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to build or find the service, is the fundamental requirement of the pattern.

What does that mean though. Should we never create a `StringBuilder` object when we use DI? The answer is no (or better yet not always). Can I create a new float without DI? Would it make sense to create a builder service and create the StreamReader from there?

You will see that `StreamReader` is a very basic implementation `public class StreamReader : System.IO.TextReader` and the classes do not even implement any other interface other than IDisposable. You can't seriously consider injecting StreamReader for IDisposable in any class.

If you want to decouple from `StreamReader` then that means that you might want to use something else in the future. You could create a `StreamService` and create your stream however you like, but at the end of the day the `StreamService` would have the Coupling as `StreamReader` can't be injected.

That's why wikipedia infers that Services are injected. Objects might be decoupled but you might want to use other patterns like **Factory**.

By the way use `StreamReader` always with the `Using` keyword so that the object can be properly disposed of.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection is powerful in some points

1. Testing : Decoupling is essential for unit testing and DI is the good way to achieve that so you can have one interface and Multiple implementations and based on what you want you can write unit test for your code and inject specific concrete class.
2. Control objects creation : It give you control on how **(specific)** objects get created and what is the life time of your objects.

So you have to know at the beginning

1. What type of classes and interfaces you want to centralize/control their objects creation ?
2. What is the functionality that if any changes happens to it in the future you want your code to keep working without big changes ?
3. In your case you are using StreamReader, it's a built-in class in C# so you have to think about How many times I'm going to use that class in my code? Do I need to change it in the future?

If I were you I'll think about two options

1. I don't care about the StreamReader it's a built-in class in C# ,it works well and I'm not going to write unit test to test the StreamReader functionality so I'll use it like what you did in your code sample.
2. I'm using StreamReader in many places in the code and I've some repeated logic I used to do every time after reading stream so I'll create IStreamReader interface with the main methods I want to use then use the DI to inject the concrete implementation.

**Note**: while using DI you are not going to Inject all the Objects in your system.